# Determining whether a timezone supports Daylight Savings Time

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

The [`TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method supports determining *whether* a given time is in DST or not, but I can't find anything which will tell me whether a given timezone supports it at all.  Is there any such thing?

Specifically, I need to write code which sends a different flag depending on whether the user's timezone is one that observes DST, **regardless of whether it's currently in DST or not**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`TimeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.supportsdaylightsavingtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = ...
if (tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 [Related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.supportsdaylightsavingtime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `StandardName` is not always equal to `Id`.  In particular, `StandardName` and `DaylightName` are localized by OS language, while `Id` is not.

Comment: @MattJohnson, you're right; I don't know how to get the `TimeZoneInfo` id from a `TimeZone` object... do you?

Comment: You can't exactly, but since `TimeZone` can only represent the *local* time zone, you might as well not use it.  Use `TimeZoneInfo.Local` instead.  Also note that MSDN recommends against using `TimeZone` at all.  See [the remarks here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @MattJohnson, good point. I'll edit my answer; it seems the OP already has a `TimeZoneInfo` anyway, so how to get it is irrelevant.

Comment: A more precise way is : TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo,Local;
if (tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime)
{
    ...
}